# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, localhost

I have this problem, I already researched and I could not solve it, I imagine it has something to do with database permissions, but I can not fix it:

```
if (error) throw error;
       ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:103:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
at Parser.write (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:253:11)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
at Connection.connect (/home/carlos/www/express-
cc/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/carlos/www/express-cc/db.js:10:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
```

**---- EDIT -----**

my env.default file:

```
NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=user
DB_PASSWORD=userpass
DB_NAME=teste
```

so this my db.js file:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql')
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database : process.env.DB_NAME,
  sockertPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
})

 connection.connect()

 connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution',
 function (error, results, fields) {
if (error) throw error;
console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].
  solution)
});

 module.exports = connection;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create a MySQL user specifically to access the app. Create a user and set a password (do not leave the password null). Do not forget to give this user permission to be able to access the database and  tables of app. I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem, all my connections were working but where I got the error '**ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)**' my call was made inside middleware at app.js level, so the .env values were not yet reachable, for this case (it could help those who have the same problem as me) I had to add:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Inside the connexion file like that :

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
require('dotenv').config();
const connectionLog = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST_LOG,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    port:process.env.DB_PORT
})
```

For me it was the resolution.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't provide db user:

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: @Techtique you see in the error message, that it lacks username and the password is not provided, so for some reason `process.env.DB_USER` neither `process.env.DB_PASSWORD` don't contain credentials from `env.default`. So it has nothing to do with db permissions.

Comment: @michaJIS So, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED  WITH mysql_native_password BY '';`

then right after doing that command flushing the privileges by executing this command:

`flush privileges;`

Answer (score 1):

You had to add the new user with an IP of the allowed host section not of the name of "localhost"

```
RENAME USER 'myuser'@'localhost' TO 'myuser'@'127.0.0.1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using `%` in place of `localhost`:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

instead of

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 1):

Check once if you've imported `environment variables` file **before** importing the `db.js` file or not.

Eg. -

Incorrect:

```
require("db.js");

const dotenv = require('dotenv');  
dotenv.config({ path: 'env.default' });
```

Correct:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');  
dotenv.config({ path: 'env.default' });

require("db.js");
```

So, first import env file, then db.js file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you face this error when you move your variables to .env file. In that case

1. Install dotenv using npm or yarn add dotenv
2. import .env using require('dotenv').config();

After this you'd be able to read your 'user' environment variable

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding a port number solves the problem ->

```
host:'localhost',
port:3406,
database:'demo_db',
user:'u_name',
password:'u_pass'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using environment variables and dotenv library make sure that you add this require('dotenv').config();....... just check it first...

const { createPool } = require('mysql')
require('dotenv').config();

```
const pool = createPool({
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0,
}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Failed to connect to Database - ", err);
});


module.exports = pool;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install env module and then create a root file .env mentioning the details of environment details:-

```
DB_NAME=yourdb_name
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=""
PORT=8080 #port_no in which your code is executing
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed the problem was by moving the `.env` file.

As indicated, the user was blank `''`:

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
```

That means the values from `.env` were not being accessed. As a test, I tried hardcoding the credentials directly into the connection configuration. It worked.

Then I moved the `.env` file and used the `.env` variables again. It worked.

Some apps require a certain folder structure. By conforming to the app's recommended folder structure, I was able to get the app to read `.env`.

Also try running commands from the same folder where `.env` is located.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my mistake was spaces in the config file...

Just as a try, you can try hard-coding your variables to test your code. If it works, there may be an issue with how your code is interacting with your config.ini source file.

Check that the path to the config.ini file is correct. In your example, you are using the relative path ../../private/config.ini, which means that the configuration file is two levels up from the currently executing PHP script. Make sure that this path is correct and that the configuration file is actually accessible from this location.

Check that the config.ini file uses the correct syntax for key-value pairs. Keys should be separated from values by an equal sign (=) and there should be no spaces before or after the equal sign. Values should be surrounded by double quotes (") if they contain spaces or special characters.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following :
mysql -u root -p
Enter password:

Create A User here and database here , After that use these details in your code.
i.e make a user by logging as root.