# error accessing mysql via terminal ubuntu 19.10

Tags: mysql

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO/YES)

I am getting the above error when I try using these command - 
`$ sudo mysql -u root 
$ sudo mysql -u root -p`

My MySQL workbench is opening properly. and I haven't set any password for root too... before when I tried using the above commands it worked  perfectly fine with and without password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue... The following solutions helped me solve it.. I figured my issue was with the root password.. so I changed the password and it worked fine for me...

[Try this first](https://techgenix.com/reset-mysql-root-password-forgotten/)

If not try @Shedrack's solution [Here this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200729/er-access-denied-error-access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-password-n)

Comment: Glad to help.. :)